# Illustrator scripting textarea

Tags: scripting, textarea, adobe-illustrator

I use a textarea in my CEP panel for Illustrator.
I've got a strange problem. When I add some characters like = or ~, they don't appear in textarea !!!
In the same way when I try to delete some characters with backspace, that don't work !!!
Why ?

Anyone have a solution ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK

In fact I use a fancytree in my panel and I forgot to deactivate keyboard !
Now it's work fine !
Sorry for I should have done more tests before posting a question!